# Why does the UK have to pay EU staff pensions if the EU have been collecting pensions contributions?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, pensions

Why does the UK have to pay EU staff pensions if the EU have been collecting pensions contributions?

Comment: It would be nice to also include a reference to an article that covers this subject (UK have to pay EU staff pensions).

Comment: I'd guess it works the same way as UK national insurance: 'contributions' now are used to pay the pensions that are being paid out now, not invested into a fund for the payee to connect in the future.

Comment: @PhillS I can't find a truly authoritative source, but it looks like the European Commission is also still running a final salary scheme. That leaves a large liability to ring fence.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I'm not sure a good answer to this question would be a good answer to that one. It would involve a discussion of pay-as-you-go, defined benefit and defined contribution pensions, along with some discussion of the precise model being followed here with only a little discussion of how that affects the EU's (as an organisation's) pension liability and assets.